# Override field validation

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have a problem:

```
public class hello{
    protected String xx;

    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty("xx")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "xx")
    public String getXx() {
        return xx;
    }

    public void setxx(String xx) {
        this.xx= xx;
    }
}

public class hi extends hello {
    @Override
    @Nullable
    @JsonProperty("xx")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "xx")
    public String getXx() {
        return xx;
    }

    @Override
    public void setXx(String xx) {
        this.xx = xx;
    }
}
```

The superclass has to validate that the `xx` attribute cannot be null, but in the subclass, it's possible to have a null value. Is there any solution?

Comment: Where do `@Nullable` and `@NotEmpty` come from? What packages? At least for `@Nullable`, if it's `org.springframework.lang.Nullable` that doesn't actually enforce any validation.

Comment: And a child class of hi could again enforce `@NotEmpty`? Definitely a case for not using inheritance, but extending hello with an almost-xx field, `getOptionalXx()` or such, and additional `isXxActuallyNull()`.

Comment: import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;